# Добавить синоним для метки [шаблоны-с++]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Стоит добавить синоним [шаблоны-c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-c%2b%2b) для [шаблоны-с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%2b%2b) (английская "си" вместо русской "эс").

---

Стоит ли вообще вводить синонимы для одинаково выглядящих на русском и английском меток, как [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)?

Comment: Мне кажется, метку с кириллической «С» надо вовсе удалить как недоразумение.

Comment: @Ainar-G почему? [tag:c] и [tag:c++] существуют в обоих вариантах

Comment: «Господе Иисусе, до чего ужасающе!».  Я бы и те удалил и забанил, честно говоря.  Либо анлийское «*C*», либо русское «си».  «Язык „эс“» — это [вон то](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_\(programming_language\)).

Comment: @Ainar-G почему? Зачем лишние проблемы при переключении раскладок, когда указываешь метки? Думаю, после удаления одной из меток она создастся в тот же день, потому что кто-то не переключил раскладку на нужную

Comment: @dIm0n Не переключить раскладку - грубая ошибка. Зачем её поощрять?

Comment: @0xdb в программировании на ЯП — да, но в контексте добавления метки в вопрос вряд ли это грубая ошибка. Для меня это такое же удобство, как и автодополнение меток. Если бы были какие-то разные смыслы у [tag:c] и [tag:с], то другое дело. Можно сделать обсуждение этого вопроса, если уже несколько человек против предложения

Comment: _но в контексте добавления метки в вопрос вряд ли это грубая ошибка_, почему-то никто не предлагает метку [пытчон], а почему "с" для языка си, почему исключение?

Comment: @0xdb потому что "си" и "эс" выглядят одинаково и находятся на одном месте в qwerty, а "пытчон" и "python" — нет. Да и маловероятно, что кто-то напишет "пытчон", скорее тогда "знерщт" :)

Comment: @dIm0n Ну так правильно же. На латинице "c" это, кроме всего прочего, ЯП, а кирилическая "с" это просто буква эс. Несуразица с "пытчон" и "знерщт" сразу заметна, а с кирилической "с" нет. Так зачем эту "незаметность" ошибки поощрять дополнительной  меткой?

Comment: @0xdb, любой человек может не заметить, что раскладка не та. И если просто удалить метку, то какой-нибудь участник случайно заведет ее заново. А если сделать метку синонимом, то при добавлении метки в вопрос просто проставится правильный вариант метки вместо неправильной.

Comment: @insolor Конечно любой может допустить ошибку. Не давая явного обратного отклика на ошибку и скрывая её "автокорректировкой", приведёт к систематическому повторению ошибки, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: @0xdb если удалить метку - проблема дублирующихся меток останется (метка вернется снова через какое то время). Если сделать метку синонимом - проблема с данной меткой будет решена. Не вижу тут ничего "нехорошего".

Comment: `но в контексте добавления метки в вопрос вряд ли это грубая ошибка` --`знерщт` ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica имелось в виду для [tag:c]

Comment: @0xdb есть метка [питон], которая синонимизирована с [python]

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Всё верно, и по аналогии должно быть "си", а не "с".

Comment: @0xdb [си] уже есть и синонимизирована с [c]

Comment: @0xdb https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/synonyms

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Не совсем понимаю, зачем вы мне пишете, вроде то же самое и имел ввиду.

Comment: @0xdb я о том, что такие синонимы уже давным-давно есть

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Всё верно, я нигде и не писал, что их нету.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Синонимы есть не просят и конечно же их стоит добавить. Другое дело, что движок не позволяет добавить синоним, если такой метки на текущий момент не существует. Например:

> [image: си-шарп-синоним]

Я в своё время предложил синонимы для [с++faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2bfaq) и [с++11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2b11) (c русской буквой "с" в начале). Получается, что такие метки существовали. Следом Николай своими модераторско-менеджерскими силами добавил и несколько смежных [синонимов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?page=4&tab=synonym&dir=ascending&filter=active):

> [image: си-нонимы]

Насколько я помню, как раз потому, что реально меток ещё не было, но чтобы можно было заодно сразу предотвратить их несвязное возможное появление.

Т.о. моя позиция проста: добавлять все возможные синонимы, а если движок против, то привлекать модераторов, сотрудников и пр.

Comment: А можно как-то призвать @Nicolas Chabanovsky, если только он это может сделать?

Comment: @dIm0n у него в профиле есть телефон. Можно позвонить :)

Comment: @dIm0n модераторы могут ещё. Но я против кириллицы в подобных тегах.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik какие доводы против? Это же синоним, под вопросом всё равно будет основная метка.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я не наблюдаю их использования. Зачем этот синоним добавлять, если его никто не использует? Вижу только [tag:шаблоны-с++].

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik чтобы потом не выщипывать такие метки, если они вдруг появятся. Звучит так как будто от наличия доп.синонимов какая-то катастрофа случится, сайт будет в 10 раз медленнее работать и т.п. Я вот не вижу никаких минусов в наличии таких синонимов, а потенциальные плюсы есть.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ просто раньше по мере появления таких меток синонимизировали.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ какую основной делать? )

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik думаю, с английской буквой, как и [tag:c++]

Comment: @dIm0n там сейчас все 536 вопросов именно с меткой, где русская буква.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik потому что в тегах автоподстановка и достаточно длинная и специфичная метка, чтобы вводить её вручную

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik а почему я смог проголосовать, если нет 2500 репутации? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/шаблоны-с%2b%2b/synonyms

Comment: @dIm0n для голосования не надо 2500, нужно только баллы (5+) по основной метке. В тексте это есть.

Answer (score 1):

Для [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) и [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) синонимы в другой раскладке нужны.

А для [шаблоны-c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-c%2b%2b) не вижу смысла, поскольку они набираются `шаб`, <kbd>вниз</kbd>, <kbd>вправо</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image: скринвидео]

Comment: Если набирать в строке поиска в самом верху, то там нет автодополнения. Собственно, так и возник вопрос :)

Comment: @dIm0n, так может тогда туда автодополнение предлагать лучше? Я вообще там только пару меток пишу, остальное приходится сначала искать на странице меток.

Comment: Думаю, будет проблематично сделать там автодополнение, учитывая что можно вводить не только метки. И если предлагать, то не на этой мете, насколько я знаю, и ждать неизвестно сколько. А синоним достаточно просто можно сделать

Comment: @dIm0n, ну в комментариях и чате же не только имена участников бывают, но после `@` автодополнение работает. Вот так же - по `[`.