# Зачем сообществу метка [центровка]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Заметил новый тег [центровка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0), оставленный явно одним участником. Вопросы:

1. Зачем сообществу эта метка?
2. Что делать, если у одного участника руки чешутся добавлять метки, а у второго подчищать за ним?

Comment: Также, посмотрите вот эти вопросы об удалениях меток - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8

Answer (score 4):

Создавать новые метки могут многие, но, это не делает все созданные метки полезными.

Например:

- метки-"опечатки" (`hmtl` или `javascrip`)
- мусорные метки (`срочно` или `всем-привет`)
- дубликаты уже существующих популярных меток (например, `виндовс` или `пи-эйч-пи`)
- прочие метки не соответствующие правилам ресурса (см. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). Для выявления таких меток есть небольшой список критериев:

  - слишком расплывчатые метки, типа `ошибка` или `microsoft`.
  - метки которые не несут смысла, если их использовать в одиночку, например `измерение`.
  - субъективые метки, типа `основы`
  - метки по которым сложно представить себе специалиста, например `умножение`

У нас есть несколько механизмов работы с метками:

- можно попросить ТС отредактировать или убрать метку.
- можно самому отредактировать или убрать метку (или попросить того, у кого есть такие привелегии)
- можно создать вопрос на Мете с предложением удаления метки силами сообщества (т.е. попросить других участников просмотреть использования метки и ее удаления/замены)
- можно создать вопрос на Мете с предложением массового удаления/запрета метки силами мод-состава (или объединения/синонимизации с другой)

Comment: [tag:c++] и [tag:с++] -- синонимы. Полезность обсуждалась в [этом посте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10713/398802)

Comment: @dIm0n не знал. Сейчас другую на опечатку исправлю тогда, чтобы избежать флейма

Answer (score -6):

1. Учитывая, что SO является саморегулируемым сообществом, то есть community-driven, то если у юзера есть такие права на создание метки, значит метка нужна.
2. Можно обсудить нужна метка или нет - вынести на голосование или поднять вопрос о повышении пороговой репутации для создания метки, но обсуждать правомерность создания метки - нет необходимости.

Comment: Нелогично. У вас, и многих других, есть права на создание метки "пыщ-пыщ-ололо". Это никоим бразом не делает эту метку нужной. Правомерность создания метки, в вопросе, не ставится, кстати.

Comment: Тут скорее надо посмотреть на вопрос с другой стороны. Вот правки участника, который добавил метку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/397819/vasily?tab=activity У него много незначительных правок, добавляющих сомнительные метки и стилистические изменения, в вопросах со своими ответами. При этом правки разнесены по времени - см. например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1158305/revisions Похоже, он таким образом поднимает вопросы на главную, чтобы привлечь внимание и срубить больше репы

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight если у вопроса строго больше одной метки, то можно просто удалять/добавлять одну из них, постоянно апая вопрос, пока не получишь ответ/нафармишь репу, а не создавать новые или делать стилистические изменения. Может быть есть/создать обсуждение на мете на эту тему?

Comment: @dIm0n У нас не было, насколько я знаю. На английском вот что нашел: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/ Судя по всему, при большом количестве правок от автора сообщения генерируется автоматическая тревога, так что модераторы будут знать. Но вопрос, есть ли аналогичный механизм, когда поднимают не свое сообщение.